# Determining the normal functionals on the direct sum of von Neumann algebras

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces, von-neumann-algebras

Consider a collection $\{M_i: i \in I\}$ of von Neumann algebras and consider their $\ell^\infty$-direct sum $M$. I'm trying to show that a normal functional $\omega$ on $M$ is of the form
$$\omega(m) = \sum_i \omega_i(m_i), m = (m_i)_i \in M$$
where $\omega_i \in (M_i)_*$ and $\sum_i \|\omega_i\|<\infty$.

In another post, user Ruy suggested to note that

$$
  (M_*)^* \cong
  M \cong
  \oplus_i^\infty M_i \cong
  \oplus_i^\infty ({M_i}_*)^* \cong
  (\oplus_i^1{M_i}_*)^*.
  $$
and then invoke uniqueness of the predual of a von Neumann algebra to obtain
$$M_* \cong \bigoplus_i^1 {M_i}_*.$$

However, to prove the above result I guess I need to know explicitely how this isomorphism looks like. How can I see this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try another perhaps more pedestrian  approach.

So we're given that  $M=\ell ^\infty (M_i)$ (I guess I prefer this notation over ${\oplus}_i^\infty  M_i$), where the $M_i$ are von
Neumann algebras.   Denoting by $M_*$ the space of normal linear functionals, we thus need to prove that
$$
  M_*=\ell ^1({M_i}_*).
  $$

Given $\omega \in M_*$, denote by $\omega _i$ the restriction of $\omega $ to $M_i$, so that $\omega _i\in {M_i}_*$, and
let us prove that
$$
  \|\omega \| = \sum_i\Vert \omega _i\Vert.
  \tag 1
  $$

Fixing  $\rho $ in the interval $(0, 1)$,  and for each $i$,  choose some  $m_i$ in $M_i$ such that $\Vert m_i\Vert =1$, and
$\omega _i(m_i)\geq \rho \Vert \omega _i\Vert $.

If $F$ is a finite subset of the index set $I$, and $m_F\in M$ is defined to have coordinates $m_i$, for $i$ in $F$, and zero
elsewhere, then $\Vert m_F\Vert =1$, and
$$
  \Vert \omega \Vert  \geq  |\omega (m_F)| = \sum_{i\in F}\omega _i(m_i) \geq  \sum_{i\in F} \rho \Vert \omega _i\Vert .
  $$
Since both $F$ and $\rho $ are arbitrary,  it follows that
$\Vert \omega \Vert  \geq \sum_{i\in I} \Vert \omega _i\Vert $.

In order to prove the reverse inequality, let $N$ be the subalgebra of $M$ formed by the elements
with finitely many nonzero coordinates.  Then, for every $m$ in the unit ball of $N$, we have that
$$
  |\omega (m)| =
  \big |\sum_{i\in I}\omega _i(m_i)\big | \leq
  \sum_{i\in I}|\omega _i(m_i) | \leq  $$$$ \leq
  \sup_{i\in I}\|m_i\|\sum_{i\in I}\|\omega _i\| \leq
  \sum_{i\in I}\|\omega _i\|.
  \tag 2
  $$

Using von Neumann's double commutant Theorem, it is easy to see that $N$ is weakly dense in $M$.  Furthermore, by Kaplansky's
density theorem, we have that the unit ball of $N$ is dense in the unit ball of $M$ relative to $\sigma (M,M_*)$, aka the weak$^*$
topology.  Therefore the inequality in (2) is preserved if, instead,  $m$ is taken  in  the unit ball of $M$.  This concludes
the proof of claim (1)

Therefore this defines  an isometric  linear map
$$
  \omega \in M_*\mapsto (\omega _i)_i\in \ell ^1({M_i}_*),
  \tag 3
  $$
and we'll be done once we prove it to be  onto.

To see that this is indeed the case, pick $(\omega _i)_i\in \ell ^1({M_i}_*)$, and
define for each subset $J\subseteq I$, the linear functional $\omega _J$ on $M$ by
$$
  \omega _J(m) =\sum_{i\in F} \omega _i(m_i),\quad\forall m\in M.
  $$

For $J$ finite it is clear that $\omega _J$ is normal,  and hence so is $\omega :=\omega _I$,  since the latter is the norm limit of the
$\omega _F$,  for $F$ finite.

Finally notice that the map in (3) sends $\omega $ to $(\omega _i)_i$, concluding the proof.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to save the original argument though?

Comment: Yes, I guess the plan outlined in your question may be carried through

Comment: @Ruy  You say "It is in fact not hard to show that the above inequality is in fact an equality". However, can you maybe provide some extra details? To me, this is non-obvious: the idea would be to approximate $\|\omega\|$ by $|\omega(m)|$ where $m$ is some unit vector and then approximate $m$ further by a finite sum $\sum_i m_i$. However, this last approximation cannot happen in the norm-topology, but I guess it will happen in the $\sigma$-weak topology and there normality of $\omega$ will have to be used. Do you agree with this?

Comment: @QuantumSpace, normality sure plays a role, as otherwise $w$ could vanish on each $M_i$ w/out being zero. Using normality one is saved by Kaplanski's density, so I agree one more step is necessary.  I'll edit as soon as I get a hold of my notebook.

Comment: @Ruy Nvm my last comments. I figured it out!

Comment: Great!  Nothing like doing it yourself!